# Emacs and jump between repositories

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm now using the awesome package "find-file-in-repository" to jump between files in different repositories, using ido to smartly complete the file path.

However one problem that I'm facing is that I constantly work on maybe 10 different respositories every day at least, so I would like to find a way to do the following.

An hypothetical function switch-to that when called:

- if I start to type a file path it behaves as find-file-in-repository
- if I type something else that should not be in a file path (for example ":") then I could switch project, and (given a hard coded list of my repositories somewhere) then complete on the filepath as before.

Is there anything like this lightweight and smart already available?
Any suggestions on other possible workflow otherwise to switch between projects and files in repositories?

I would like to avoid to have all the possible files in my repositories in a single completion list because it gets very slow and harder to find what I'm looking for at that point..

Comment: Maybe use a different buffer naming policy? Have a look at [`uniquify`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Uniquify.html).

Comment: Well not really I don't have control on file names across different repositories..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried [`projectile`](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile)? With it you can do `projectile-switch-project` and it will prompt with all the projects you have worked on, once you have selected the project it will prompt you for the file you wish to open in *that* project. Plus it has some other goodies like `grep-in-project`, `replace-in-project` etc.

P.S. It recognizes `git`, `mercurial`, `darcs`, `bazaar` repos as projects.

Comment: Plus, it's maintainer is really helpful, and cares a lot about feedback.  If something is missing for you, don't hesitate to open an issue on Github.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anything like this lightweight and smart already available? Any suggestions on other possible workflow otherwise to switch between projects and files in repositories?

Yes.  Use Emacs ***bookmarks***.  You can bookmark practically anything, including "repositories" or sets of repositories or pieces of a repository.

[***Bookmark+***](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/BookmarkPlus), in particular, is your friend.